# Excel vba count headers and copy active row of same length to new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to vba and struggling with a macro.

I have recorded a macro and then tried to adapt it.

What I have is a list of drivers as headers currently c1:t1 but as I add or remove drivers I need the selection below to adapt.

B2 is a merged cell (B2:B5) with the date in and the columns across are still individual cells.

The date is repeated all the way down in the same format for each day of the year.

What i'm trying to do is select a date and press ctrl+q and copy the list of drivers names across the headers to a new sheet in column A and the selected date and the number of columns to match the number of drivers in the header.

```
Sub Macro6()
'
' Macro6 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'

    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Daily").Select
    Range("C4:F4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False



    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 14
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With

        Sheets("Weekly").Select
        Range("c1", Range("CV1").End(xlToLeft)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Daily").Select
        Range("A5").Select
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-27
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("Weekly").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

        Sheets("Daily").Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    Selection.ClearContents
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

    Selection.ClearComments
    Sheets("Weekly").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

[image: Weekly]
[image: Daily]

Comment: A screenshot of the data + the code that you tried would definitely help... :)

Comment: upload the image to somewhere, and put the url in the question. usually, a kind (higher reputation) user will change the question to show your image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim lCol As Long, cpycel As Range
Set cpycel = Range(ActiveCell.Address)
lCol = (Sheet1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) - 1
cpycel.Resize(4, lCol).Select

Selection.Copy
Sheets("Daily").Select
Range("C4:F4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Weekly").Select
Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(1, (lCol + 1))).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Daily").Select
Range("a4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells((lCol + 3), 6)).Select
```